# How to open Modal popup on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have this link-button:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)"><button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btn">Read More</button></a>
```

I want `onclick` hit, a modal popup appears with all the article details.I have tried a lot until now but nothing runs properly.Any ideas?

UPDATED

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false
})
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 500,

        buttons: {
            Accept: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
});
```

UPDATED (image)

[image: RESULT]

Comment: always include what you have tried so far from there SO people can point out what went wrong

Comment: I updated my question!This is something I tried but no results.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Bootstrap , please see below example

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modelWindow" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm vertical-align-center">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Heading</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Body text here
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>



$('#btn').click(function() {
   $('#modelWindow').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: I can see the modal but for some reason it is located on the left of the page and I can notice only the close button.If I shrink the page then it is displayed properly.Any ideas?

Comment: @platanas20  move the modal div out of everything , just keep it in body , not in other sections.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is with this code:

```
<a href="">
```

As there is no value in href, so whenever you'll click on the button actually it will click on that anchor tag and the page will refresh. You can use this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
```

Or on the click function you can get the event and use preventDefault.

Hope this will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right!I updated my question.please have a look if you like.

Comment: please write the js code in document.ready function and then try again. Thanks.

Comment: I did it but nothing changed

Comment: on your updated image I can see the modal on left side. But it looks like css issue. Somehow it went outside your viewport. Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I didn't see your answer!It was `css` issue and I think I fixed it!Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I get it without using some custom css or js. It works with bootstrap.js and bootsrap.css.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<!--> Your Dialog Field -->
<div class="dialog">
      Some Text Some Captions and/or images etc..

     <button class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Show More</button>
</div>
 
<!--> Your Modal Field -->
<div class="modal" id="modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modallabel1" aria-hidden= "true">
      <h1>Some Text for the Modals
      Some Text for the Modals
      Some Text for the Modals
      Some Text for the Modals</h1>
</div>
</html>
```

There are better examples ([Bootstrap Modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)), but this works without own js.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow instructions to use Booststrap Modal Popup

**Step:-1**

Add Bootstrap Modal Container

**Step:-2** Add Button to Show Modal Popup
                                   Save

```js
   
   function getBuiltyUpdateForm(id, dcNo) {
      
       $('#builtyUpdateModal').modal('show');
   }
   
   
       function saveRecord() {
      alert{"It's Working"}
   }
```

```html
   
   
                           <a onclick="getBuiltyUpdateForm()" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-lg m-t-n-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"    title="Update"></i></a>
                           
 <div class="container">
   
   <div class="modal fade" id="builtyUpdateModal" role="dialog" style="margin-left:0px">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title">Add Builty Number</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-md-3">
                               <label>DC Number</label>
                               <input id="dcNo" onkeypress="return isCharacter()" onpaste="return false;"    ondrop="return false;" type="text" data-validation="required"    data-validation-error-msg="DC number is required" disabled    autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                               <p id="dcNumber"></p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-3">
                               <label>Builty Date</label>
                               <div class="input-group date">
                                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                   <input id="builtyDate" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Date is    required" data-validation-error-msg-container="#builtyDate"    class="form-control custom-date-picker" type="text"    value="31-May-2022" disabled />
                               </div>
                               <p id="builtyDate"></p>
                           </div>
   
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                               <input type="hidden" id="hdndcId" />
                               <label>Builty Number</label>
                               <input id="builtyNumber" autofocus type="text" data-validation="required"    data-validation-error-msg="Builty number is required"    autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                               <p id="builtyNumber"></p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button"   onclick="saveRecord()" class="btn btn-primary"    data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>    </div>
```

**Step:-3**
       Write HTMl Code For Modal
            
       
           
               ×
               Add Builty Number
           
           
               
                   
                       
                           DC Number
                           
                           
                       
                       
                           Builty Date
                           
                               
                               
                           
                           
                       
   
                       
                           
                           Builty Number
                           
                           
                       
                   
               
           
           
               Submit
               Close

```js
   function saveRecord(){    alert("It's Working")    }
```

```html
   
 <div class="modal fade" id="builtyUpdateModal" role="dialog" style="margin-left:0px">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title">Add Builty Number</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-md-3">
                               <label>DC Number</label>
                               <input id="dcNo" onkeypress="return isCharacter()" onpaste="return false;"    ondrop="return false;" type="text" data-validation="required"    data-validation-error-msg="DC number is required" disabled    autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                               <p id="dcNumber"></p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-3">
                               <label>Builty Date</label>
                               <div class="input-group date">
                                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                                   <input id="builtyDate" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Date is    required" data-validation-error-msg-container="#builtyDate"    class="form-control custom-date-picker" type="text"    value="31-May-2022" disabled />
                               </div>
                               <p id="builtyDate"></p>
                           </div>
   
                           <div class="col-md-6">
                               <input type="hidden" id="hdndcId" />
                               <label>Builty Number</label>
                               <input id="builtyNumber" autofocus type="text" data-validation="required"    data-validation-error-msg="Builty number is required"    autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                               <p id="builtyNumber"></p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" id="builtyNumberUpdatebtn" onclick="saveRecord()" class="btn    btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

```js
   function saveRecord(){    alert("It's Working")    }
```

```html
   
 <div class="modal fade" id="builtyUpdateModal" role="dialog" style="margin-left:0px">
       <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title">Add Builty Number</h4>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-body">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <div class="col-md-3">
                               <label>Field 1</label>
                               <input id="dcNo" onkeypress="return isCharacter()" onpaste="return false;"    ondrop="return false;" type="text" data-validation="required"    data-validation-error-msg="DC number is required"  autocomplete="off"    class="form-control" />
                               <p id="dcNumber"></p>
                           </div>
                           
   
                           <div class="col-md-3">
                               <input type="hidden" id="hdndcId" />
                               <label>Field 2</label>
                               <input id="builtyNumber" autofocus type="text" data-validation="required"    data-validation-error-msg="Builty number is required"    autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                               <p id="builtyNumber"></p>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" id="builtyNumberUpdatebtn" onclick="saveRecord()" class="btn    btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```